# Meteor templates - how to add pagination to a table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

In my meteor app I have the following templates:

```
<template name="users">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid"> 
            <div class="page-header">
              <h1><small>Users List</small></h1>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id='userTable'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   {{#each userList}}
                    {{>userRow}}
                   {{/each}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<template name="userRow">
     <tr class="userRow">
        <td>{{name}}</td>
     </tr>
</template>
```

What should I do to add pagination (of any kind) to this table?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Discover Meteor](http://book.discovermeteor.com/) yet? It has a pretty good chapter on pagination.

Comment: Just purchased it about 5 minutes ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSwe_weshQw) that answers your question.  Many props to George (geomck1967) for making such a great series of Meteor videos!